# Access the class using this in JQuery

Tags: jquery

In the below code i want to access the `product-price` class using `this` operator. How can i do it within another class

```
$(".product-attributes").click(function()
{
    $(".product-price").hide();
    $(".price").show();
});
```

tis is my prob. When tis page loads i display a minimum price value and wen i click d qty values i display the respective prices. But wen i click d qty of one item al the items minimum price also changes. I want only d price of tat item which i click to change

[image]

This is my HTML code

```
echo "<div class='product-attributes' style='position:absolute;top:10px;display:none;'>";

    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product)
    {   
        $simple_product_price = strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()));
        $simple_product_drink_size = $simple_product->getAttributeText('drink_size');       
        $simple_product_id = $simple_product->getId();
        $simple_product_name = $simple_product->getName();
        $simple_product_url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($simple_product);
        $updateUrl = str_replace('add','updateItemOptions',$simple_product_url);

        echo "<span class='product-attribute-elem product-attribute-".$simple_product_id."' title='".$simple_product_id."' >" . $simple_product_drink_size .
        "</span><input type='hidden' class='product-attribute-".$simple_product_id."-price' value='".
        $simple_product_price."'/><input type='hidden' class='product-attribute-".$simple_product_id."-url' value='".$simple_product_url."'/>".
        "<input type='hidden' class='product-attribute-".$simple_product_id."-name' value='".$simple_product_name."' >".
        '<span class="qtyUpdater-'.$simple_product_id.'" style="display:none">'.
        '<span onclick="NewAjaxAddCart(this,\''.$updateUrl.'\',\'-\',\'.category-products\');" class="Qmins">&nbsp;</span>'.
        '<input type="text" onchange="NewAjaxAddCart(this,\''.$updateUrl.'\',\'upd\',\'.category-products\');"  value="0" >'.
        '<span onclick="NewAjaxAddCart(this,\''.$updateUrl.'\',\'+\',\'.category-products\');" class="Qplus">&nbsp;</span></span>'; 
    }
    echo "</div>";

endif; ?>

                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>                

            <?php echo "<div class='price'></div>"; ?>
            <?php echo "<span align='center' class='product-price'>".$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)."</span>"; ?>
```

Comment: Please post full code for better answer

Comment: Just do something like `$(".product-price").css('visibility':'hidden');` and `$(".price").css('visibility':'visible');`

Comment: I cant post the whole code.. Its a complicated process..The concept is simple -- i want to access the this operator of another class within a class

Comment: @Venktesh could you possibly show an example of what you want to do and how it isn't working?

Comment: @Phil I hav shown an image now... Check it out..

Comment: @Venktesh No, a **code example** >:(

Comment: @Phil Code example i cant show because its a huge and comlpicated code

Comment: @Venktesh Please read this before asking a question - http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @Phil I have put up d code.. Check it out and solve it now

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.find()`,

```
$(".product-attributes").click(function(){
   $(this).find(".product-price").hide();
   $(this).find(".price").show();
})
```

Comment: @Venktesh Without a proper representation of your problem, we could not do anything.

Comment: I hav shown an image now.. Check it out..

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong, but this answer works pretty fine for me. Check out the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37Aqc/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted do like this:

```
$(".product-attributes").click(function()
{
    $(".product-price", this).hide();
    $(".price").show();
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a46p6/)

Comment: I checked d demo but product-attributes and product-price classes are not nested. They are seperate

Comment: you should provide html for that.

Comment: I have put up d code.. Check it out and solve it now